# What is the explanation of this method using PreparedStatementCreator in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, class, prepared-statement

I never used this class `PreparedStatementCreator` and normally when I want to execute a query I do something like: `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c...) values (?,?,?...)`, but in this case the MySQL query is: `INSERT INTO table() values()` ??

Can you explain me that? I can't understand how the columns are tracked...

The following code is the method. Thanks in advance:

```
public String add(String identificationNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String cellphone,
            String city, String gender, BloodType bloodType, ShirtSize shirtSize, String emergencyContactName,
            String emergencyContactPhone, String eps, Long birthday, Integer isVolunteer, Group group) {

        PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO participants() VALUES()";
                return con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            }
        };

        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(psc, keyHolder);
        String id = keyHolder.getKey().toString();

        modify(id, identificationNumber, firstName, lastName, email, cellphone, city, gender, bloodType, shirtSize,
                emergencyContactName, emergencyContactPhone, eps, birthday, isVolunteer);

        if (group != null && !Utilities.emptyString(group.getId()))
            setGroup(id, group);

        return id;
    }

public void modify(String id, String identificationNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String email,
            String cellphone, String city, String gender, BloodType bloodType, ShirtSize shirtSize,
            String emergencyContactName, String emergencyContactPhone, String eps, Long birthday, Integer isVolunteer) {
        Object[] args = new Object[] { identificationNumber, firstName, lastName, email, cellphone, city, gender,
                bloodType == null ? null : bloodType.toString(), shirtSize == null ? null : shirtSize.toString(),
                emergencyContactName, emergencyContactPhone, eps, birthday, isVolunteer, id };
        String sql = "UPDATE participants SET identificationNumber = ?, firstName = ?, lastName = ?, email = ?, cellphone = ?, city = ?, gender = ?, bloodType = ?, shirtSize = ?, emergencyContactName = ?, emergencyContactPhone = ?, eps = ?, birthday = ?, isVolunteer=?  WHERE id = ?";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer to this, is very simple:

1. Inserts a row empty in the table.
2. Then gets the id of that row.
3. Calls modify to INSERT (really UPDATE the row).

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change following SQL :

> String sql = "INSERT INTO participants() VALUES()";

Add Field name into `participants()` and add ? into `VALUES()`.

Then you need to set the each ? value by following statements,

```
ps.setString(1, "test");
```

for each ? you need to set the values.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: that method works fine, your answer is suposed to be the normal way, but this works and I don't understand how?... this is a class of Spring Framework

Comment: check this 
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator